# how can we use Angular with sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, angularjs

I am new to SharePoint development. My senior has asked me to use angular with SharePoint. Can anybody provide me any guidance about how we can use angular with SharePoint? Which version of angular will work with SharePoint 2010 and which will work with 2013? if we have jsom then why we need to learn angular?

Answer (score 1):

AnularJs is famous for its two-way data binding. If you want to take this advantage, then you can go for AngularJs. Otherwise, you should use JSOM. Moreover, REST API in SharePoint 2010 is not that much rich. For business logic (Angular Service), you have to depend on JSOM. You have to choose Angular version based on your IE version. Check following references.

[Notes on Using AngularJS in SharePoint 2010](https://niftit.com/angularjs-in-sharepoint-2010/)

[Internet Explorer Compatibility of AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

In SharePoint 2013, REST API is much more powerful. Thus, you can consider using it. Some useful links are given below:

1. [CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)
2. [SharePoint REST API and AngularJs for 2013, 2016 and Online](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1115141/REST-API-and-AngularJs-for-SharePoint-and-Online)

Comment: What are the steps to implement Angular 2 in the SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

jsom is a development model with a set of libraries and classes provided by SharePoint where you can use any JavaScript Framework and angular js is one of them.

You can use any version of Angular Js for any SharePoint Version. But suggested version is angular v1 because this version has a lots of third party open source library which can help in your development.

This a [post](http://www.deepakvirdi.com/2015/crud-operations-using-angular-rest-services-sharepoint-2013/) which can be helpful. There are lots other blog posts which you can find easily.

Thanks and hope that this will help you.